# Java clip frame position is stuck

Tags: java, audio, clip

Lots of people are battling the java clip class. I have pinpointed a problem not addressed on any other question I found:

```
.... code to set up clip from AudioSystem.getClip()
// Everything seems to be OK:
clip.open(...);
clip.isRunning(); //false
clip.getMicrosecondLength(); // 2 000 000
clip.getFrameLength(); // 10 000
clip.setFramePosition(0);

// Lets run it:
clip.start();
clip.drain();
clip.getFramePosition(); // STILL 0!
```

No sound plays (of course), and the function exits almost immediately rather than taking 2 seconds to drain. What could be causing this?

Comment: I had issues with `drain` when multiple `Clip`s where been used (either had finished, were playing or hadn't started yet).  I ended up using a `LineListener`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886549/audio-file-plays-in-eclipse-ide-but-not-as-jar-file/29886855#29886855). As to "why" it happens, I have no idea :P

Comment: You might also consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I avoided it by finding a library that plays sound.