# issue with audio(mp3) not always playing, and is no longer playing

Tags: java, audio, mp3

To start, it played really laggy. next time i ran it it went pretty smoothly. now it wont play at all. I set it up with a youtube tutorial, and cannot find anything different from my code to theirs. this is what i believe the issue is. i have searched extensively on audio in java, and havnt found success yet. This is what i found in debugging:

```
"terminated"Game [Java Application] 
"disconnected"game.Game at localhost:51874  
"terminated, exit value: 0>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe (Oct 16, 2015, 7:23:49 PM)
```

replace "" with <> for the debugging above as for some reason <> wont show
and i also got this error code

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
at audio.AudioPlayer.<init>(AudioPlayer.java:30)
at game.Game.main(Unknown Source)
```

Im not sure what to make of this, and i have searched the internet to no avail.

here's my code.
Java project:
Game
src-
     (package) audio
     (class) AudioPlayer

```
 package audio;

 import javax.sound.sampled.*;

 public class AudioPlayer 
 {  
private Clip clip;

public AudioPlayer(String s)
{
    try
    {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                                getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));

            AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();
            AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(
                    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    16,
                    baseFormat.getChannels(),
                    baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    false
                    );

        AudioInputStream dais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                                decodeFormat, ais);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(dais);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public void play()
{
    if (clip == null) return;
    stop();
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}
public void stop()
{
    if (clip.isRunning())
    {
        clip.stop();
    }
}
public void close()
{
    stop();
    clip.close();
}
```

}

(package) game
(class) Game

```
 package game;
 import audio.AudioPlayer;
 public class Game
 {
static boolean w = true;
private static AudioPlayer BGMusic;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    if (w = true)
    {
        BGMusic = new AudioPlayer("/Music/Opening.mp3");
        BGMusic.play(); 
    }
}
```

}

Here is what else i have in the java project
     Resources-
          Music-
               Opening.mp3
     JRE System Library
     Referenced Libraries-
          /Game/Libs/tritonus_share.jar
          /Game/Libs/mp3spi1.9.5.jar
          /Game/Libs/jl1.0.1.jar
     libs-
          /Game/Libs/jl1.0.1.jar
          /Game/Libs/mp3spi1.9.5.jar
          /Game/Libs/tritonus_share.jar

Comment: The base audio subsystem doesn't support all MP3 ecnodings, you could look JLayer from JavaZoom

Comment: I got the mp3 from a youtube video, with youtubetomp3.org or something like that. woulf getting the download from a different site make it work? or maybe not from youtube?

Comment: and why would it play sometimes and not others?

Comment: I was playing around with it and it works when i use a while statement- while (w = true). it keeps starting a new "song" while the original still plays. i guess i could use a key action event etc to have it work, but i am still curious as to why it doesnt work with an if statement.

Comment: Because it's not compatible with base audio system. There could also be an issue with how the decoding is done between the hardware/software decoding implementations within the API. You could try using wave file instead

Comment: i tried just changing w to false after the BGMusic.play(); but it didnt stop the repeated staring

Comment: is there anywhere i can find what MP3 encodings is supported?

Comment: That's interesting, the [`mp3spi*.jar` belongs to JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html).  Do you have a link to the MP3 file?

Comment: i used this youtube video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdJQopRuH1E, and just converted it to mp3. im not sure how i could post an mp3 file on this site

Comment: if i were to use a wav instead, how would i change the formatting done in AudioPlayer?

Comment: Don't normally need to worry about it. I've been trying to get the mp3spi installed, but haven't had much time to look into it yet

Comment: im not sure if this helps, but i got this error code while running the while statement. ill add it to my post

Comment: Were you ever able to figure anything out?

Comment: Install the `jl1.0.1.jar`, `tritonus_share.jar` and `mp3spi1.9.5.jar` files in your JRE's `ext` directory, `{jre}/lib/ext`.  That seems to have worked for me

Comment: I've done that, but i still have the same issue. an if statement doesn't run the file, but a while statement will run it continuously (every second or so another clip starts of top of the other crashing the program)

Comment: The audio system is using a daemon thread, meaning that when main exits, the jvm is terminated

Comment: How would I edit the code to resolve that issue? I'm not too well versed in audio, so I'll look into threads later this week.

Comment: Well, depending on what you want to achieve, you could use `Clip#drain`, demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886549/audio-file-plays-in-eclipse-ide-but-not-as-jar-file/29886855#29886855), but I've had issues with it in the past and used a `LineListener` instead, but my code was running a GUI, so the main `Thread` wasn't exiting

Comment: I f'n LOVE you man. You just saved me sooo many head aches!

Comment: Good, send me some aspirin ;)